# No simulator option while running the code

Tags: iphone

I am not able to see Simulator option in my XCODE for one of my project (Only device is there) but it is coming for other one. What setting I need to do?

Comment: you mean probably the newest beta SDK 4.2 which comes with Xcode 3.2.5? I downgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because I was trying to build the app on IOS 4.0 which was missing in my XCODE.